# Create a relationship between USERS in writing REVIEWS

Tags: c#, sql, .net, postgresql, entity-framework

Want to create a Reviews table and got confused what foreign keys I need to place there. I want the ability  of **ONE** user leave Reviews on the page of **SECOND** user. here is my current model. What do I need to add there?

**REVIEWS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace sellwalker.Models
{
    public class Review : BaseEntity
    {
        public int ReviewId{get;set;}
        public string Content{get;set;}
        public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;}
        public int UserId{get;set;}
        public User Reviewer {get;set;}


    }
}
```

**USERS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace sellwalker.Models
{
    public class User : BaseEntity
    {   

        public int UserId{get;set;}
        public string FirstName{get;set;}
        public string LastName{get;set;}
        public string Email{get;set;}
        public string Password{get;set;}
        public string Status{get;set;}
        public string ProfilePic {get;set;}

        public List<Order> Orders {get;set;}
        public List<Product> products {get;set;}
        public List<Review> Reviews {get;set;}
        public User()
        {
            Orders = new List<Order>();
            products = new List<Product>();
            Reviews = new List<Review>();
        }
    }
}
```

With current table I can write reviews but I want to link it to the special user. System doesn't let me add one more UserId there so what is the best solution here?

Comment: You mean one user may create many reviews, and one review may come from many users?

Comment: Have you looked to ForeignKey attribute? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could go with something like that:

Review Model:

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //...

    public int ReviewerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Reviewer { get; set; }
    public int ReviewedUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User ReviewedUser { get; set; }
}
```

User Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //...

    public virtual ICollection<Review> WrittenReviews { get; set; } = new HashSet<Review>();
    public virtual ICollection<Review> MyReviews { get; set; } = new HashSet<Review>();
}
```

And then you have to specify the connections using fluent API because EF wont know wich navigation property belongs to wich.

Fluent API Code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.ReviewedUser)
    .WithMany(x => x.MyReviews);

modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Reviewer)
    .WithMany(x => x.WrittenReviews);
```